# Empty value coming in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery = $.noConflict();
function onCheck(){
  var rowvalues=jQuery(".rowvalues").val();
  alert(rowvalues);

}  
</script>
```

and my page is

```
<type input="hidden" value="{!rowNum}" class="rowvalues" name="rowvalues" />
```

In rowNum I'm having a value of 100.But in my alert it is showing empty value.Don't know why.Help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your HTML the wrong way round:

```
<type input="hidden"
```

should be

```
<input type="hidden"
```

Also, its not clear where you're calling the `onCheck` function from. Are you sure the page is completely loaded before you call that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try printing the value without setting a variable to take out less factors in the problem.

There are three ways I know of in JQuery to accomplish this

```
alert($('input#foo').val()); # If you add an ID
alert($('input[name=row values]').val());
alert($('input[type=hidden]').val());
```